# Analog multimeter reading DC voltage unprecisely

Tags: voltage, multimeter

How do we fix and/or calibrate an analog multimeter reading DC voltage rather inaccurately?

- 24 V is read 26 V
- 12 V is read 13 V
- 1.25 V is read 1.5 V

It worked normally three years ago.  It was left untouched since then.

Comment: What does the meter manual tell you about calibration?

Comment: What make is the meter? Is a quality brand which can be sent back for calibration?

Comment: Type of meter?  Is the voltage being measured from a power supply or circuit?

Comment: Take the batteries out.  Disconnect the leads.  Does the needle point at the zero (0) mark, or does it show something higher?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that this meter gives consistently-low readings.

Possible causes of *loss of calibration*:

- Meter was dropped.
- bearings too tight.
- Needle balance/suspension disturbed.

Keep in mind that D'Arsonval movements are delicate. Rotating bearings are precisely made and easily damaged.
A sharp blow can also affect the permanent magnet, almost always causing a permanent decrease of its magnetic field...causing readings to be consistently low.
Sometimes a shard of magnetic material is caught between coil and magnet poles. This usually causes erratic readings.

Too-tight bearings can cause erratic readings as well.

Sometimes the suspension springs tangle, causing restoring force to change. You can usually spot this with a visual inspection.

Multimeters are usually meant to be read while lying on their back. Panel meters are usually meant for vertical mounting. A meter attempts to balance the moving parts so gravity doesn't affect readings. Does the zero reading change when moving from vertical to horizontal? If so, balance may be off.

A *very-high-quality* meter may provide a mechanism to calibrate - look for a magnetic shunt that diverts a small amount of the permanent-magnet's flux. A magnetic shunt is adjustable - increasing its air-gap should make the meter more sensitive.
An internal variable resistor might divert some coil current from the D'Arsonval's movement, providing a means of calibration. Don't start twiddling just any variable resistor - ohm scale is often adjusted this way too.

---

Tap the meter gently after it has settled to a given position...does the reading change? If so, bearings or suspension-spring or a magnetic shard are the suspects.

Comment: it seems that this meter gives consistently high resaings

Comment: @Neil_UK you may be right -  I find *"...is read..."* confusing/ambiguous.